# Lab: 2.14 LAB - Select tall horses with subquery

Tags: sql, subquery

Exercise Instructions:

The Horse table has the following columns:

ID - integer, primary key

RegisteredName - variable-length string

Breed - variable-length string

Height - decimal number

BirthDate - date

Write a SELECT statement to select the registered name and height for only horses that have an above average height. Order the results by height (ascending).

Hint: Use a subquery to find the average height.

Here is what I wrote:

```
SELECT RegisteredName, Height
FROM Horse
WHERE AVG(Height)
    (
    SELECT Height
    FROM Horse
    WHERE Height
    )
```

I have tried many different alterations to this as I am new to SQL, but cannot seem to find where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The subquery only needs to return a single value (the average height) then all rows in the table can be compared to that value:

```
SELECT
      RegisteredName
    , Height
    -- more columns as needed
FROM Horse
WHERE Height > (SELECT AVG(Height) FROM Horse)
```

Answer (score 0):

If window functions are supported :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, AVG(Height) OVER () AS AvgHeight
  FROM Horse
) s
WHERE Height > AvgHeight
```